# Help regarding terminology on Korean history: 정화오례신의, 주자가례, 진사시, 재지지주, 강남농법, 등

Tags: transliteration, sino-korean-words, technical-terms, middle-korean

No matter how hard I try to understand these terms, I can't find clear explanations. If anyone cares to concisely describe each terms and what the English terms are, you'd save my life.

-정화오례신의

-주자가례

-진사시

-재지지주

-강남농법

-실사구시

-종법제도

-개원래

-치례

-문복최질

And terms like 삼헌, 분헌, 집사, 찬축....

감사합니다!

Comment: Are these all words in a passage that you're translating?

Comment: Please show the context in which these words appear and generally some more research effort, including your own attempt at translation.

Comment: These are words that most Koreans will only ever encounter in high school history classes.  (In fact I can't even recognize some of these terms, and I grew up in Korea.)  If you need to have English translation of these terms, you're probably reading something way above your Korean reading level.  (You're supposed to be at least at the level of a native Korean high schooler.)

Comment: (...And if you're reading something that uses these terms but does *not* explain them, you're probably reading something aimed at history majors at college.  Even I would need a dictionary to read such a document.)

Comment: My Korean language level is definitely not on par as a highschool student. I'd say I'm at an elem. school level. But I'm a grad student and the class is conducted in Korean, so I have no choice but to do the readings which are written in academic Korean of course. There are no provided explanation for every terms because I think we're expected to know those terms already. But it's only my 3rd week in class & my undergard degree is not related to Korean-studies specifically.

Comment: I have an idea of what all these terms are but I'm a bit doubtful of myself so I'm using stackexchange as just another method to reassure myself that I do have the correct meanings based on what I searched on my own.

Comment: Normally on stack exchange we try to ask and answer questions in a way such that they can be as useful and interesting as possible to other users of the site. I've asked a [meta question](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/could-help-with-translating-larger-passages-be-on-topic-and-if-so-whats-the-b) about how we can do that for this type of question - but for now perhaps it would be good if you can put the original reading passage in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Koreans learn their history, and learn a bunch of Sino-things. They're even not Sino-Korean. **They're totally in 漢文, Chinese writings.** Sadly, it's quite different from our current language. The cultural connection as well.

To me, whenever I learn the history, it was quite frustrating to be unable to understand those. For example, in schools, we learn that 정조 (正祖) wrote some books: <대전통편>, <동문휘고>, <탁지지>, <추관지>, <규장전운>. I cannot even guess the Han characters of them; **we don't learn the meaning of each character.**

What I want to say is, that you should ask this on *History Stack Exchange* or *Chinese Stack Exchange*. Things at that time was rather Chinese.

---

Well, according to [the Japanese *Wikipedia*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BF%E5%92%8C%E4%BA%94%E7%A4%BC%E6%96%B0%E5%84%80), 정화오례신의 (政和五礼新儀 / 政和五礼新仪)<sup>[[1]](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BF%E5%92%8C%E4%BA%94%E7%A4%BC%E6%96%B0%E5%84%80)[[2]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%94%BF%E5%92%8C%E4%BA%94%E7%A4%BC%E6%96%B0%E4%BB%AA)[[3]](http://folkency.nfm.go.kr/kr/topic/%EC%B4%88%EC%A2%85/464)</sup> is a 儀禮書 (의례서: a book about formality.) and was written on late ***Northern Song*** dynasty, completed by Emperor *Huizong* of ***Song*** **in 1113**. For my best guess, `政 (정)` means `politics`, `和 (화)` means `-ish` or `and`, `五 (오)` means `five`, `礼 (례)` means `formality`, `新 (신)` means `new`, `儀 (의)` means `rules`: so it would likely mean either `Politics and five new rules for formality` or `Five new politic rules for formality`.

---

And so on. Hmm, I think *Wiktionary* would be good for you to do this work: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/政](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%94%BF).

Comment: [政和 is the era name (연호)](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%A0%95%ED%99%94_\(%EB%B6%81%EC%86%A1\)) of Emperor Huizong of Song.

Comment: @droooze Oh, then it would mean `五礼新儀 of 政和`: `Five new rules for formality of the year 1110's`! (I guess)

Answer (score 1):

- 정화오례신의 (政和五礼新儀) - A book of etiquette/rites compiled during the reign of Emperor Huizong of Song.
- 주자가례 (朱子家禮) - A book of etiquette/rites of the household (common rites, coming of age rites, weddings, funerals, commemoration rites), authored by Zhu Xi.
- 강남농법 (江南農法) - Agricultural techniques of China's Yangtze (Yangzi) Delta region (江南 is the region of China located to the south of the Yangtze River, near Shanghai). *Quote from the Journal of Korean Studies, Volume 15, No. 1 (Fall 2010): "There is a general concensus among the scholars of Korean history that the introduction of the agricultural method of China's Yangzi Delta is the key to understanding and evaluating early Choseon agricultural development."*
- 실사구시 - possibly 實事求是, a four-character idiom meaning *seeking truth from facts*, or being practical and realistic.
- 종법제도 - possibly 宗法制度, meaning the institutions in a society revolving around a patriarchal clan system (which ancient China was based around). This blood relation governs everything relating to inheritance.
- 치례 - something to do with rituals. Second syllable should be 禮, unsure about the first.
- 집사 - possibly 執事, which can refer to many things including a *court official*, *deacon* (in Christianity), *court attendant*...

I can't even make an educated guess on the other ones - you haven't provided enough context.

*In general, you will get a better answer if you put in some more research effort to help us help you answer the question. For the Chinese-related literature consider finding the Hanja for the words and asking the question on Chinese StackExchange.*